# label based on related features

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, loop, relationship-class

Esri's telecom data model has 2 geometric networks, one for infrastructure (manholes and conduits) and one for fiber cables.

fiber cables are easily related to a section of conduit based on existing relationship class.

How can you label the conduit in a way that shows all the fiber cable_ID's that are related to that conduit?